# inverse of abstract matrix

Tags: matrix, tensors

If you assume the matrix $A$ is invertible, then $A^{-1} \cdot A = I$.
Is there an assumption for invertibility in Mathematica 9? How can one make the following evaluate to the identity matrix $I_3$?

```
$Assumptions = {Element[A, Matrices[{3, 3}]]}
Inverse[A].A
```

Comment: Look at the `Tensor*` functions.  Specifically, pass your result to `TensorReduce` or `TensorExpand`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This gives what you want! Adding the axiom of matrix power $A^0=I$ to `Simplify` gives us

```
Simplify[
Assuming[Element[A, Matrices[{n, n}]] && Det[A] != 0,TensorExpand[Inverse[A].A]], 
ForAll[{A}, MatrixPower[A, 0] == IdentityMatrix[n]]]
```

> IdentityMatrix[n]

Use `n=3` to validate your case.

Comment: Why is the axiom of matrix power not assumed by default?

Comment: Perhaps because `0^0` is an indeterminate expression that can be both 0 and 1 with a sensible definition. One has `0^x = 0` but also `x^0 = 1`. With `0^0`, they contradict each other, one has to make a call. Perhaps Mathematica does not make that for the user.